# Flaw in a "dice deck"?

Tags: probability

I happened to run into this product today:
https://www.thegamecrafter.com/games/ultimate-geek-dicedeck

It immediately bothered me, since (without *quite* claiming it) the creator seems to imply that he can simulate several consecutive rolls of a die without needing to shuffle this deck.

I was trying to think of some simple way of proving that this is, in fact, impossible with this kind of design. Assuming a die with 4 faces and a deck size of $2n$, here's the closest I could get:

# of sequences of possible die rolls of length $n$: $4^n$

# of permutations of the "dice deck": $(2n)!$

Then for the "dice deck" to perfectly simulate the appropriate odds, it must be true that $4^n = 2^{2n} \mid (2n)!$. But this is impossible via, say, de Polignac's formula.

I feel like there's some missing link in the above argument, however. Must, in fact, $2^{2n} \mid (2n)!$?

Comment: You are correct, that $2^{2n}$ never divides $(2n)!$ and thus this technique can't work. It might be "good enough," for all real purposes, but it can't be perfect. (And shuffling is a far from perfect randomization method.)

Comment: Another way to see that it can't work perfectly to simulate all $n$ rolls is to realize that when you're down to the last two cards, you know exactly which cards they are, the only uncertainty being their order, so there are only two possible outcomes instead of four.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that suggests the question, for a given size deck, how many dice rolls can you accurately simulate in this fashion? $k=1$ is self-evidently doable, but is more possible?

Comment: @ sappidus: I doubt that even $k=2$ works unless you can replace cards.

Comment: @CarlHeckman, please see my answer, which confirms your doubt.

Comment: It works fine if the deck has a countably infinite number of cards.  Just number them $1,2,3,\dots$ , draw one card for the first roll, and take $\bmod 4$.  You still have the same chance for $1,2,3,4$ after each draw.

Comment: @RossMillikan, yeah, but try to (physically) *shuffle* that deck!

Comment: @RossMillikan There is no such thing as picking a random element with equal probability from a countable set. A thoroughly random shuffle would give such a random selection (by taking the first element of the deck after a shuffle,) so you are stuck again, unless you are allowed to pick randomly from a subset of the permutations, where if $a_i\equiv a_j\pmod {4}$ and $i<j$ then $a_i<a_j$. But that's sort of cheating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Carl Heckman speculated in comments, you can't even simulate *two* fair rolls of a $4$-sided die by drawing two cards at a time (without replacement).

Enumerate the $2n$ cards in the deck and consider the $2n\times2n$ matrix whose off-diagonal entries $a_{ij}$ (with $i\not=j$) are the simulated-die result of drawing the $i$th card first and the $j$th card second.  Picking two cards at random is equivalent to randomly picking one of these $2n(2n-1)$ entries.  If you are simulating a *fair* $4$-sided die, there must be an equal number of entries for each outcome, hence $4\mid 2n(2n-1)$, which means $n$ must be even, say $n=2m$.  But then the simulated *second* roll is equivalent to picking a random off-diagonal entry from a $(2n-2)\times(2n-2)$ matrix, formed by simply deleting the rows and columns corresponding to the two cards of the first draw.  No matter which rows and columns were removed, the smaller matrix has $(2n-2)(2n-3)=2(2m-1)(4m-3)$ entries, which is *not* a multiple of $4$, so the second draw cannot simulate a fair roll.

This works even if you start with an odd number of cards.  In an arbitrary $N\times N$ matrix, you have $N(N-1)$ off-diagonal terms.  If $4\mid N(N-1)$ then $4\not\mid(N-2)(N-3)$.

Final remark:  The video demonstation at the linked-to site shows a shuffle that results in all $n$ simulated rolls resulting in a "$1$."  It's possible what the designer has created is a deck for which, given any of the $4^n$ possible results of rolling a $4$-sided die $n$ times, there is at least one shuffle that simulates that $n$-tuple.

Comment: Excellent answer! This reasoning doesn't seem to quite work for, say, a d6 die, though. Any ideas there?

Comment: @sappidus, you are quite right, you might be able to simulate two rolls of a d6 die (but not three).